# Calculating payment breakages

Tags: sql-server-2008, cursor, except

I'm currently working on a report to highlight payment breakages, this is based on a customer paying in June, but then failing to pay in July.

I've currently got it set up to do an except query, to check one month and compare it to the next. Similar to below(syntax my not be correct as I have had to edit certain data).

```
DECLARE @StartDatePaid AS DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDatePaid AS DATETIME
DECLARE @StartDateMissed AS DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDateMissed AS DATETIME

SET @StartDatePaid = '01-Oct-2013'
SET @EndDatePaid   = '31-Oct-2013'
SET @StartDateMissed = '01-Nov-2013'
SET @EndDateMissed = '05-Dec-2013'

SELECT        d.StoreNo   
                , d.CustNo
FROM (
--Paid Range
SELECT     c.CustNo, m.StoreNo 
FROM         dbo.tblCont AS c INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tblContDep AS cd ON c.ContractNo = cd.ContractNo INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tblCust AS m ON c.CustNo = m.CustNo INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tblTrans AS mx ON m.CustNo = mx.CustNo AND cd.AgendaCode = mx.AgendaCode INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tblCalender AS cl ON mx.DateEvent  = cl.Date 
WHERE     (cd.Payment > 0) AND (m.Closed <> 'Y') AND (cd.AgendaCode <> 'OPCLIPMT')
                                 AND mx.DateEvent BETWEEN @StartDatePaid AND @EndDatePaid 
GROUP BY c.CustNo, m.StoreNo, mx.DateEvent 
EXCEPT 
--Missed Range
SELECT     c.CustNo, m.StoreNo
FROM         dbo.tblCont AS c INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tblContDep AS cd ON c.ContractNo = cd.ContractNo INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tblCust AS m ON c.CustNo = m.CustNo INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tblTrans AS mx ON m.CustNo = mx.CustNo AND cd.AgendaCode = mx.AgendaCode INNER JOIN
                      dtLookups.dbo.tblCalender AS cl ON mx.DateEvent = cl.Date 
WHERE     (cd.Payment > 0) AND (m.Closed <> 'Y') AND (cd.AgendaCode <> 'OPCLIPMT') AND (mx.DateEvent BETWEEN @StartDateMissed AND @EndDateMissed )
GROUP BY c.CustNo, m.StoreNo, mx.DateEvent
      ) AS d 
      WHERE d.StoreNo IN (72, 114, 121, 139, 185, 241, 266)
      GROUP BY 
                      d.StoreNo, d.CustNo
```

I will be switching it over to be based on calendar months instead of date ranges, my question is how am I best generating several months of breakages at once. To get a month on Month comparison at once, as it is I can only get it to create one months breakages based on supplied data.

Example of desired output

```
Month| breakges
June | 201
July | 189
Aug  | 250
```

Open to suggestions on best practice also or ways to improve.

Answer (score 0):

I admit I don't understand your query. Assuming your breakage is the first occurrence of missing payment, not the subsequent ones. You can produce the desired output like this:

```
-- prepare your source data
with cte1 as
(
  select 
    user_id, 
    date, -- representing month by the first day
    missed -- bool flag if payment was missed in that month
    from ...    
)
-- add a sequence number to the source data ordered by date
with cte2 as
(
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by user_id order by date) rn
  from cte1
)
-- select those records where payment was missed but the previous was ok
,cte3 as
(
  select user_id, date from cte2 a
  where a.missed = 1
  and exists (
    select * from cte2 b 
    where b.missed = 0
    and b.uid = a.uid 
    and b.rn = a.rn -1
    )
)
select date, count(*) as breakage from cte3 group by date
```